# C# "does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments"

Tags: c#

I've posted something like this a bit ago and it helped out but i had issues afterwards and couldn't do anything. SO I'M BACK!

```
Time time1;
private void btnNewTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Time time1 = new Time(Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text)));


        }
```

and in the time class:

```
        public Time()
        {
            hour = 12;
            minute = 00;
        }//end of Time

        public Time(int Hour, int Minute)
        {
            hour = Hour;
            minute = Minute;
        }//end of Time
```

It's suppose to go into the parameterized constructor (the second one) But i get the error:

"does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments"

Comment: Please use consistent code formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a typo, a misplaced parentheses.

```
Time time1 = new Time(Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Time time1 = new Time
    (
      Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim()), 
      Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text)
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a parenthesis after the first trim to close the Convert.ToInt32 (Also lose one of the last parenthesis on the end).

And, your first construct of `Time` can be:

```
public Time()
  :this(12,0)
{
}
```

Or, if you have VS2010/.NET4 you can now use [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public Time(int Hour = 12, int Minute = 0)
{
  hour = Hour;
  minute = Minute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only providing 1 argument to the constructor:

```
Time time1 = new Time(Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text)));
```

You need to close the first arguments 2nd set of parenthesis:

```
Time time1 = new Time(Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a typo:

```
Time time1 = new Time(Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text));
```